# Nightwatch: wait for element without pass/fail result

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

Related questions:

- [wait for element present without error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051214/wait-for-element-present-without-error)
- [Nightwatchjs: how to check if element exists without creating an error/failure/exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687027/nightwatchjs-how-to-check-if-element-exists-without-creating-an-error-failure-e)
- [Selenium WebDriver : Wait for complex page with JavaScript(JS) to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720325/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-complex-page-with-javascriptjs-to-load)

Whenever I load my web-page, I need to wait for ajax calls to complete. I currently do this with:

```js
browser.waitForElementNotPresent(
  "cssSelector_For_HTML_afterAJAXComplete",
  10000 //timeout
);
```

This adds an extra assertion to my test though, and makes the test-count for the report artificially larger than necessary.

Any ideas?

Comment: It turned out that using [nightwatch-cucumber](https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-cucumber) gives me the necessary wrappers to make nightwatch test reports more fitting. I recommend using this library for your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I hacked something together. I'm basically sending javascript to the console in selenium using `browser.execute(function, params, callback)`

```
  function waitForElement_NoPassFail(selector, timeout){
    browser.execute(function(selector, timeout, done){
      let intervalId;
      var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        intervalId = setInterval(function(){
          let itemArray = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
          if(itemArray.length == 1){
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            resolve(true); //element found
          } else if(itemArray.length>1){
            reject(false); //too many elements found, because of ambiguous selector
          }
        }, 100);
      });
      var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(reject,timeout, false); //timeout reached
      });
      return Promise.race([p1, p2]).then(function(result){
        done(result);
      });
    },
    [selector, timeout],
    function(result){
      if(!result){
        throw "Element: " + selector + " wasn't found after " + timout + " ms.";
      } else {
        console.log("Element found within timeout limits.") //doesn't trigger assert=ok
      }
    });
  };

  waitForElement_NoPassFail(
    "cssSelector_that_Is_Valid_after_AjaxIsComplete",
    10000 //timeout
  );
```

This can be extended in various ways, for example to support xPath. You could use the nightwatch global variable for element checking frequency when waiting. Write a comment if you need the help.